# Bug - Search and Reset filter button does not work on Shopping cart tab - backend (Manage customers)

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0

I believe it is a bug in Magento. I've confirmed same on new magento installation 1.8.1.0 and on 1.8.0.0.

'Search' and 'Reset filter' buttons does not work on Shopping cart tab - backend (Manage customers). When checked using firebug, it displays an error - **ReferenceError: id_38724ef8c3ffc5020408a02bbe80530eJsObject is not defined**

Edit:
Found nothing except this link: https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/issues/36 which provides no help!

If anyone has found a solution, please share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue by overriding the block **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Cart**

Set Id of the block on `_construct()`

```
public function __construct($attributes=array())
{
    Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::__construct($attributes);
    $this->setId('customer_cart_grid' . $this->getWebsiteId()); // added code
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->_parentTemplate = $this->getTemplate();
    $this->setTemplate('customer/tab/cart.phtml');
}
```

And changed the url in `getGridUrl()` from **/cart** to **/carts**

```
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('* /* /carts', array('_current'=>true, 'website_id' => $this->getWebsiteId()));
}
```

Hope it helps someone :)